# Как перебрать api в компоненте React'a?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-router

Мне нужно пройтись циклом по компоненту Authors и возвратить

`<Route path={"/authors/" + item.id} component={Author}/>`

А в компоненте Author нужно получить автора по id с сервера.
Как из ContentFeed вытащить this.state.items?

буду рад помощи.

```
const Authors = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/authors/id" component={Author}/>

  </Switch>
)
const Author = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={} width={"150px"}/>
            <h3></h3>
            <p><b>Дата рождения:</b></p>
            <p><b>Дата смерти:</b></p>
            <Link to={'/'}><b>BACK</b></Link>
        </div>
    )
}

class ContentFeed extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            items:[]
        }    
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getItems();
    }
    getItems(){
        fetch('http://localhost:3001')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => this.setState({items: response}))
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <Table columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.items}/>
                <Authors data={this.state.items}/>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

локальный сервер

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.json([{"key":"1","bookname":"book1","author":"author1","date":"31.04.1867","src":"http://localhost:3001/exp1.jpg"},{"key":"2","bookname":"book2","author":"author2","date":"01.10.1959","src":"http://localhost:3001/exp2.jpg"},{"key":"3","bookname":"book3","author":"author3","date":"21.07.2010","src":"http://localhost:3001/exp3.jpg"}]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал по другому.
Я бы создал 1 роут:

```
<Route path="/authors/:id" component={Author}/>
```

Получил бы ваш список с сервера, сделал бы список линков:

```
{items.map((item, i) => <Link key={i} to={`/authors/${item.key}`}>{item.bookname}</Link>}
```

А в самом компоненте `Author` я бы достал переданный айди из пропс:

```
const {match: {params: {id}}} = this.props;
```